# java.awt requestFocusInWindow doesn't work on ubuntu

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

I want have a very easy effect: 
create a window, then if I press a button, it will be closed.

So I write the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final Window wnd = new Window(new Frame());
        wnd.setLocation(100, 100);
        wnd.setSize(400,300);
        wnd.setVisible(true);
        wnd.requestFocusInWindow();


        wnd.addKeyListener(
          new KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
            {
              wnd.setVisible(false);
              wnd.dispose();
              System.exit(0);
            }
          }
        );
   }
}
```

I guess the problem may be lie in:

```
wnd.requestFocusInWindow();
```

because the returned value of wnd.requestFocusInWindow() is always "false". Why? How can I fix the problem? (I use ubuntu and Eclipse.)

Comment: 1) Why use AWT components rather than Swing?  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6255978/418556) for many good reasons to abandon AWT. 2) `wnd.setFocusable(true);`

Comment: Thanks Andrew, the answer link is really useful! I learn the GUI programming just at beginning, may be I can now skip the chapter about "awt" and direct go to "swing".

Comment: *"skip the chapter about "awt" and direct go to "swing""*  Yes!